styling a table with multiple rows inside the <TD>
I am trying to display 5 columns table inside a panel . Below is what I am trying to do that is not working properly:

I want SKU, Description, Unit price, Quantity and Amount to be displayed in one single line rather than up and down and then I want service fee to come as $0.69 on next line and then at the bottom, I want "Total amount paid" with 32.69 displayed on one line. description and  amount is coming from code behind and the digits can change to be three digits or two digits. I want something like this below image to be displayed with the titles at the top that says SKU, Description, Unit price, Quantity and Amount.

This is the code that I tried:


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Transaction Details</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <table  >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">SKU</th>
              <th scope="col">Description</th>
              <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
              <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
              <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
              <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td ><span id="lblSKU">CCB</span>
                  <br /><br /><br /><br />
                  Total Amount Paid
              </td>
              <td >
                  <span id="lblDesc">chocolate Certificate</span>
                  <br /><br />
                  <span id="lblServFee">Service Fee</span>
              </td>
              <td ><span id="lblUnitPrice">$32.00</span></td>
              <td><span id="lblQuantity">1</span></td>
               <td><span id="lblAmount">$32.00</span>
                   <br /><br />
                    <span id="lblServiceFee">$0.69</span>
                    <br /><br />
                   <span id="lblTotAmount">32.69</span>
               </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



is it possible to align the digits too in the amount column.  any help will be appreciated.

<br>'s shouldn't be used to try and force a lay-out instead you should use a <tr> for each product/item in your table, by doing this you are creating a row for each product, aligning everything nicely


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Transaction Details</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">SKU</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="lblSKU">CCB</span></td>
            <td><span class="lblDesc">chocolate Certificate</span></td>
            <td><span class="lblUnitPrice">$32.00</span></td>
            <td><span class="lblQuantity">1</span></td>
            <td class="text-right"><span class="lblAmount">$32.00</span>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Service Fee</td>
            <td><span class="lblServiceFee">$0.69</span></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="text-right">$0.69</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Total amount paid</td>
            <td class="text-right">$32.69</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Note: I've used colspan on the Total amount paid to "bridge" the gap, so this td will actually use 4 columns instead of 1, otherwise you would need to define 3 extra empty td's
PS: ID's should be unique and can only be used once on an element in HTML, therefor I've replaced all the ID's with a class
